# PythonVirtualenvOperator as custom plugin in Amazon MWAA?

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

Anyone tried the [custom plugin for Apache Airflow **PythonVirtualenvOperator**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-virtualenv.html) in Amazon MWAA (Amazon Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow)?

I properly followed all the steps described there, but I get a "*No such file or directory: 'virtualenv': 'virtualenv'*" error when I run the dag.

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I am facing the same issues

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue (DAG Import Error - PythonVirtualenvOperator requires virtualenv, please install it)

Comment: trilson86, did you get this to work? I get PythonVirtualenvOperator requires virtualenv and I followed all the instructions in the link provided in the question above. I am about to post a detailed question about this.

Comment: This is answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/72203130/833960. The PythonVirtualenvOperator code supplied on the AWS website is incorrect.