# MWAA - Airflow - PythonVirtualenvOperator - Which Python versions can I specify with python_version=

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, airflow, python-venv, mwaa

I am using [MWAA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/what-is-mwaa.html) with the [PythonVirtualenvOperator](https://registry.astronomer.io/providers/apache-airflow/modules/pythonvirtualenvoperator) installed using the instructions on [AWS Site](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/samples-virtualenv.html) with this [additional fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72203130/833960).

It is working ok, I am able to have different DAGs install different versions of [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) within virtual environments.

The MWAA [FAQs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/mwaa-faqs.html#python-version) specify that Python version 3.7 is supported for MWAA, but that doesn't clarify if this limitation applies to PythonVirtualenvOperator and pyenv.

I wanted to try the *python_version=* argument to the *PythonVirtualenvOperator()* function, to set different python versions. When I specify:

```
python_version="3.8"
```

I get the following errors in MWAA log:

```
RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.8'
```

**Dag Source Code**

```
from platform import python_version
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python import PythonVirtualenvOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


def virtualenv_fn_5():
    import boto3
    import sys

    print("boto3 version ", boto3.__version__)
    print(f"This is printed from the dag script: {__file__}")
    print(f"Python version: {sys.version}")


with DAG(
    dag_id="virtualenv_test_5",
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
    start_date=days_ago(1),
) as dag:
    virtualenv_task = PythonVirtualenvOperator(
        task_id="virtualenv_task_5",
        python_callable=virtualenv_fn_5,
        python_version="3.8",
        requirements=["boto3==1.17.1"],
        system_site_packages=False,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

**Log**

```
*** Reading remote log from Cloudwatch log_group: airflow-mwaa-environment-public-network-MwaaEnvironment-Task log_stream: virtualenv_test_5/virtualenv_task_5/2022-05-18T01_53_13.871659+00_00/1.log.
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1035}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: virtualenv_test_5.virtualenv_task_5 manual__2022-05-18T01:53:13.871659+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1035}} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: virtualenv_test_5.virtualenv_task_5 manual__2022-05-18T01:53:13.871659+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1241}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1242}} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1243}} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1262}} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonVirtualenvOperator): virtualenv_task_5> on 2022-05-18 01:53:13.871659+00:00
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{standard_task_runner.py:52}} INFO - Started process 799 to run task
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{standard_task_runner.py:76}} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'virtualenv_test_5', 'virtualenv_task_5', 'manual__2022-05-18T01:53:13.871659+00:00', '--job-id', '118', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/holder_folder/virtualenv_test_5.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmp46ax8anc', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpi6bk2idu']
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{standard_task_runner.py:77}} INFO - Job 118: Subtask virtualenv_task_5
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{logging_mixin.py:109}} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: virtualenv_test_5.virtualenv_task_5 manual__2022-05-18T01:53:13.871659+00:00 [running]> on host ip-10-12-12-12.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1429}} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=airflow
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=virtualenv_test_5
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=virtualenv_task_5
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-05-18T01:53:13.871659+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=manual__2022-05-18T01:53:13.871659+00:00
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{process_utils.py:135}} INFO - Executing cmd: python3 /usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv /tmp/venvswu6o8zm --python=python3.8
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{process_utils.py:139}} INFO - Output:
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{process_utils.py:143}} INFO - RuntimeError: failed to find interpreter for Builtin discover of python_spec='python3.8'
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1703}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1458, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1514, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 365, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 151, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 381, in execute_callable
    requirements=self.requirements,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/python_virtualenv.py", line 96, in prepare_virtualenv
    execute_in_subprocess(virtualenv_cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 147, in execute_in_subprocess
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python3', '/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv', '/tmp/venvswu6o8zm', '--python=python3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1280}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=virtualenv_test_5, task_id=virtualenv_task_5, execution_date=20220518T015313, start_date=20220518T015314, end_date=20220518T015314
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{standard_task_runner.py:91}} ERROR - Failed to execute job 118 for task virtualenv_task_5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 92, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 292, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 184, in _run_raw_task
    error_file=args.error_file,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1332, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1458, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    result = self._execute_task(context, self.task)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1514, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 365, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 151, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 381, in execute_callable
    requirements=self.requirements,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/python_virtualenv.py", line 96, in prepare_virtualenv
    execute_in_subprocess(virtualenv_cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 147, in execute_in_subprocess
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python3', '/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/virtualenv', '/tmp/venvswu6o8zm', '--python=python3.8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2022-05-18, 01:53:14 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:154}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-05-18, 01:53:15 UTC] {{local_task_job.py:264}} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: It's not clearly documented, but mwaa uses 3.7, and it probably only support 3.7 for `PythonVirtualenvOperator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment above by 0x26res, *MWAA PythonVirtualenvOperator* only supports Python 3.

The version of Python used by MWAA is currently, as at 19th May 2022, 3.7.10:

```
print(f"Python version: {sys.version}")
```

Produces:

```
[2022-05-19, 00:01:46 UTC] {{logging_mixin.py:109}} INFO - Python version: 3.7.10 (default, Jun  3 2021, 00:02:01)
```

The only working values for the *python_version* argument of *PythonVirtualenvOperator* currently seem to be:

- 3
- 3.7
- 3.7.10

Anything else causes the exception shown above.

In practice, this makes usage of the *python_version* argument of *PythonVirtualenvOperator* useless other than to assert the usage of a specific python version. We can't use *python_version* within *MWAA* *PythonVirtualenvOperator* to select a different python version.